# How to get build expression (c=>c.user.code == 'XXX') dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I'v build a method to construct expression dynamically, below is my code:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildStringEqualLambda(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    ParameterExpression parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
    Expression propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);
    Expression right = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);
    Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(propertyExp, right);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(e1, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExp });
}
```

But if the lambda like

```
c=>c.user.code == 'XXX'
```

and I invoke method like below:

```
BuildStringEqualLambda("user.code","XXX");
```

The method report error.

So my question is how to get build  expression (c=>c.user.code == 'XXX') dynamically

Comment: "The method can't deal it." what do you even mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
ParameterExpression parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
Expression propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);
```

You need to go deeper for each property:

```
ParameterExpression parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
Expression propertyExp = parameterExp;
foreach (var property in propertyName.Split('.')) {
    propertyExp = Expression.PropertyOrField(propertyExp, property);
}
```

Comment: The Initial value of propertyExp is what?

Comment: @user2155362 I Updated my answer